# Mongoose retrieval of info from multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a resume building app with Mongoose and Express. I set my models up so that education and work experience are both in their own collections. something similar to this:

```
"degree" : "BA",
"major" : "Econ",
"minor" : "Bus. Admin",
"startDate" : ISODate("2013-12-31T00:00:00Z"),
"endDate" : ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
"user" : "example@gmail.com",
"created" : ISODate("2013-10-15T19:32:09.357Z"),
"_id" : ObjectId("525d9839ddc8bf7855000001"),
"school" : {
    "name" : "university of alabama",
    "loc" : "austin, tx"
},
"__v" : 0
```

I have a reference to the _id of the User model in the "user" value. my User model looks like so:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
_id: {type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true, validate: validEmail }
, name: { first: String, last: String}
, salt: {type: String, required: true}
, hash: {type: String, required: true}
, edu: [{type: String, ref: 'Education'}] });
```

When I try to populate the edu section of my User model with information from the education model it's not finding anything.

My query is this:

```
var query = User.findById(user)
    .populate('edu');
```

So how would I properly allow my User model make references to the education model so that I can send info from both to a view? Could I populate to fields like that?

Any advice would be mega helpful. I'll be scouring the docs, google and trying random things that kind of make sense in the mean time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` type in order for `populate` to work properly.

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
_id: {type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true, validate: validEmail }
, name: {first: String, last: String}
, salt: {type: String, required: true}
, hash: {type: String, required: true}
, edu: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Education'}] });
```

---

side note:

- you don't need to define `_id` as you get that automatically and it should not be an email. Use a separate email field for that.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I actually just figured that out. The part I was having trouble with was saving the reference of the edu doc to the user doc, but I ended up just using the .save() function and that ended up doing what I wanted to do. Thanks again for the help though.